# Tomcat applications won't enter debug through intellij on OSX

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

I am following this book  [Wrox Java for Web Applications](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-Java-for-Web-Applications.productCd-1118656466.html)

I have Tomcat 8 set up on my macbook pro which is running OSX Mavericks. When I ever I set a break point in Intellij it just gets ignored. I tried the same in Eclipse and it worked.

I really like Intelij so if I could get it working that be great. Does anyone have any suggestions as to what could be in the issue? I am using Intellij 13.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

If you're launching Tomcat from IntelliJ then make sure that you launch it debug mode, otherwise breakpoints won't work.

If your Tomcat is external then you can add this to the JVM parameters to enable debuggers to talk to it: `-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=5005,suspend=y`